# INSERT INTO do not work in PROCEDURE

Tags: mysql

here is my PROCEDURE

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Transakcje()
BEGIN
DECLARE ile INT DEFAULT 1;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp
(
Ilosc int
);

WHILE ile <= 11 DO
    INSERT INTO temp (Ilosc) VALUES (ile);
    SET ile = ile + 1;
END WHILE;

INSERT INTO Sprzedaz (KlientId, ProduktNumer, Ilosc , Cena)
SELECT k.KlientId, p.ProduktNumer, t.Ilosc, t.Ilosc*p.Cena AS Cena FROM klient AS k, produkt AS P, temp AS t;

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

When I run it all looks okey but INSERT INTO do not work. When i run my INSERT INTO separately it do what i want. I do not know what i do wrong.

Comment: There are 2 inserts in your stored proc, which insert are you talking about? Is there any error message?

Comment: My bad, I mean the second one INSERT INTO Sprzedaz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the alias of produckt from `P` to `p` (capital to lower case) like so:

```
INSERT INTO Sprzedaz (KlientId, ProduktNumer, Ilosc , Cena)
SELECT k.KlientId, p.ProduktNumer, t.Ilosc, t.Ilosc*p.Cena AS Cena FROM klient AS k, produkt AS p, temp AS t;
```

Example:

```
create table klient (klientid int); insert into klient values (1),(2);
create table produkt (produktnumer int, cena int); insert into produkt values (1, 1), (2, 2);
create table Sprzedaz(klientid int, produktnumer int, ilosc int, cena int);
create table temp (ilosc int); insert into temp values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11);

SELECT k.KlientId, p.produktnumer, t.Ilosc, t.Ilosc*p.Cena AS Cena FROM klient AS k, produkt AS P, temp AS t;
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'p.produktnumer' in 'field list'

SELECT k.KlientId, p.produktnumer, t.Ilosc, t.Ilosc*p.Cena AS Cena FROM klient AS k, produkt AS p, temp AS t;
-- getting good results by changing alias from capital P to lower case p

INSERT INTO Sprzedaz (KlientId, ProduktNumer, Ilosc , Cena)
SELECT k.KlientId, p.ProduktNumer, t.Ilosc, t.Ilosc*p.Cena AS Cena FROM klient AS k, produkt AS p, temp AS t;
-- insert works great
```

With this change your stored proc should insert correctly